# How to set asset manifest path for each request

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I have an `rails-4` application with multiple themes. Each theme has it's own assets (stylesheets,images,javascripts).

I have overwritten asset `prefix path` and compiled the assets.

In initializer `configuration.rb`

```
Empty::Application.configure do
  config.assets.prefix= "../../Sites/assets/#{ENV['Theme']}/assets"
end
```

`ENV['Theme']` I am  passing like

```
 RAILS_ENV=production Theme=theme1 rake assets:precompile
```

It compiled all the assets and placed in the path I have given.

Same thing I have overwritten the assets `prefix` path and `manifest` path in application controller and calling the method in `before_action`.

```
Rails.application.config.assets.prefix = "/assets/#{@site.theme.name}/assets"
```

and

```
Rails.application.config.assets.manifest  = "#{Rails.root}/../Sites/assets/#{@site.theme.name}/assets"
```

But it is always taking the `manifest` and `prefix` path as `public/assets` instead of my custom path.

It was working in `rails-3`.

I am using `Rails-4.2.4`, `Sprockets-2.12.4`, `Sprockets-rails-2.3.3`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the source for finding an asset path. It seems like if you add a `relative_url_root` to the `config` in `application.rb` you could manually set this.

```
def asset_path(source, options = {})
  source = source.to_s
  return "" unless source.present?
  return source if source =~ URI_REGEXP

  tail, source = source[/([\?#].+)$/], source.sub(/([\?#].+)$/, '')

  if extname = compute_asset_extname(source, options)
    source = "#{source}#{extname}"
  end

  if source[0] != ?/
    source = compute_asset_path(source, options)
  end

  relative_url_root = defined?(config.relative_url_root) && config.relative_url_root
  if relative_url_root
    source = File.join(relative_url_root, source) unless source.starts_with?("#{relative_url_root}/")
  end

  if host = compute_asset_host(source, options)
    source = File.join(host, source)
  end

  "#{source}#{tail}"
end
```